# how to build a Form component in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, building

I am newbie to React.js and I m trying to build the form builder in react - something similar to this https://formbuilder.online/ - 
I got started with buttons from very beginning - I am trying to add a text field via one of the methods after the button is pressed - and it doesn't make any difference at all to the code. As in at-least it should print something in console but doesn't. Please help!!

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


export default class EditForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { values: [] };
    }


handleChange = (i, event) => {
  console.log("handle clicked test clear")
     // let values = [...this.state.values];
     // values[i] = event.target.value;
     // this.setState({ values });
  }


handleAddfeild = () => {
  return this.state.values.map((el, i) =>
     <div key={i}>
        <input type="text" value={el||''} onChange=    
 {this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
     </div>); 
// console.log("should add text field");
};


handleClearfeild = () => {
console.log("should remove the added feild")
};

handleSaveform = () => {
console.log("will save this form using node API")
}



render() {
 return (
   <div className="container-fluid">
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddfeild}
          className="small">Add Text Feild
          </button>

          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSaveform}
                  className="small">Save Form
          </button>

          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClearfeild}
                  className="small">Clear
          </button>

  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `state.values` array is empty, so there is nothing for `map()` to execute against.  Try adding something to `state.values` in your constructor.

Comment: @PhilipWrage that's technically right b/c in the beginning there shouldn't be something in the beginning right?

Comment: Correct.  But at the moment your `handleAdd()` method does not actually add anything to `state.values`, so you have nothing to display.  For testing purposes, try adding a value using `this.setState()` to `state.values` to ensure something displays when the `handleAdd()` method is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `handleAddfeild` function should be adding an item into the (values?) array of your state. It doesn't need to return anything though. You should loop over the array in your render function instead.

here is an example of what that may look like

[image: Edit zljp13932m]

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class EditForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { values: [] };
  }

  handleChange = (i, event) => {
    console.log('handle clicked test clear');
    // let values = [...this.state.values];
    // values[i] = event.target.value;
    // this.setState({ values });
  };

  handleAddfeild = () => {
    let fields = this.state.values;
    fields.push({ value: '' });
    this.setState({ values: fields });
    // console.log("should add text field");
  };

  updateFieldValue = index => event => {
    let fields = this.state.values;
    fields[index].value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ values: fields });
    event.persist();
    return false;
  };

  handleClearfeild = () => {
    console.log('should remove the added feild');
  };

  handleSaveform = () => {
    console.log('will save this form using node API');
  };

  render() {
    const fields = this.state.values.map((field, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={field.value || ''}
            onChange={this.updateFieldValue(i)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddfeild} className="small">
          Add Text Feild
        </button>

        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSaveform} className="small">
          Save Form
        </button>

        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClearfeild} className="small">
          Clear
        </button>

        {fields}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: right, it makes sense to me to use a loop in the render function instead of the methods above. OK thanks gazillion @Daniel - its got me started nicely - I was trying to loop it in the methods. I wonder if that's good approach in the long run

Comment: you can create your view/render components, like the list of values, and store them in your state, so you don't recalculate them every time you render. But that will likely end up with code that's more difficult to manage for little benefit. So I would say, unless you have a good reason to do so, generate your view from your state during render and let react handle the details until you are more comfortable with react.

Comment: thanks loads!! I'll use render function from now on.. @Daniel